# How to sent message to the NIC of our own computer?

Tags: ipc, nic

I want to transfer a message to the NIC of my computer, without using another computer. I actually want to capture packets that pass through my NIC. Ideally that would require 2 other computers in my network that are exchanging information and that information is passing through my NIC also, but obviously getting rejected because its not meant for me. But can I not sent packets to my own NIC, and capture them ?

Using loopback address doesn't work as probably the message doesn't go to the NIC.

Answer (score 0):

Connect it to a hub.  Then it will have a signal so the NIC will work.

Comment: i have only a pc, no hub or router